# Call the name of the database in the active mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql

This might be a basic question but i couldn't find the answer..

How do i reference the name of the table being called in the myself query without needing to define it manually.

right now i use

```
    const mysqlDB = require(`../../../functions/mysql.js`);
    sql = "SELECT * FROM test_table ORDER BY id";
    mysqlDB.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        message.reply(`Returning **${result.length}** results from **test_table** table.`);
```

and the only way i know how to reference the table name being called is by defining like this, which i'd like to avoid if possible

```
const mysqlDB = require(`../../../functions/mysql.js`);
sql.table = test_table;
sql = `SELECT * FROM ${sql.table} ORDER BY id`;
mysqlDB.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

message.reply(`Returning **${result.length}** results from **${test_table}** table.`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is theoretically possible with a simple, one table query and the right library.  But using Node.js MySQL (which I'm guessing you're using), it doesn't seem possible.  The results is simply the rows, nothing more.

Also, as soon as your query gets any more complicated and contains multiple tables, it's very unclear how this would work.

So assuming this only works with a single table query, why not just use a variable name?

If you REALLY want that table name in the query results, make your query something like...

```
SELECT *, 'test_table' as 'table_name' FROM test_table ORDER BY id
```

Now your table name is part of your response.